# Confused about the definition of a Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, monomorphisms

A particular author defines a Field Extension as a monomorphism (to be more detailed, as an injective homomorphism) between two Fields.

However, my idea of a Field Extension is that of a pair of Fields in which the 'smaller' Field is contained in the 'larger' one; in the sense that each element of the 'smaller' field is in the 'larger' one.

For me, a monomorphism seems different that a Field Extension. Am I missing something?Is the author maybe defining something else? Is my idea of a monomorphism wrong?

---

I would really appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: Given an injective homomorphism $\varphi: E \to F$ of fields, one can identify $E$ with its image $\varphi(E)$.  These two fields $E$ and $\varphi(E)$ are not equal, but they are "the same," i.e., isomorphic.  Since $\varphi(E) \subseteq F$, once you've made this identification you can think of $E$ as being a subset of $F$.

Comment: A ring homomorphism between fields is always injective!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $i: F \to F'$ is a monomorphism of fields, then $i[F]$ is a subfield of $F'$ and is isomorphic to $F$. So both views come down to the same thing, as long as we don't care about differences between isomorphic fields.

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is a field and $K$ is a subfield, then there is a natural monomorphism $\iota\colon K\longrightarrow F$; it is defined by $\iota(x)=x$.

And if $\iota$ is a monomorphism from a field $K$ into a field $F$, then $F$ has a subfield isomorphic  to $K$, which is $\iota(K)$.